# .htaccess -> Redirect all requests to certain folder, but NOT when it begins with /public

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, redirect

#### What I want

I want to redirect all requests that does not start with `/public` to `/public`. I want this to be done with a `.htaccess` file.

#### Here some examples:

Example without `/public` in it:
https://www.example.com/css/main.css -> https://www.example.com/public/css/main.css

Example with `/public` in it:
https://www.example.com/public/js/main.js -> https://www.example.com/public/js/main.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: This works, but is there also a way to do this redirect. But not showing the /public/ ? So the url still stays like example.com/css/main.css (but it go's to example.com/public/css/main.css internaly) ?

Comment: @PROMIKE360 try it without the 'R' flag in the rewrite rule